# Difference between foreach and iterate in smarty

Tags: smarty

What is difference between {iterate} and {foreach} in smarty tpl files?
are they different in using 'from' phrase?

Comment: I don't see `{iterate}` listed in their documentation. Is it a plugin that you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no command called "iterate" in Smarty.  There is, however, a command called {section} that is often confused with {foreach}.

From the documentation at [Smarty.net](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.section.tpl):

> The {foreach} loop can do everything a {section} loop can do, and has
>   a simpler and easier syntax. It is usually preferred over the
>   {section} loop.

Also:

> {section} loops cannot loop over associative arrays, they must be
>   numerically indexed, and sequential (0,1,2,...). For associative
>   arrays, use the {foreach} loop.

Hopefully that helps.